# Just installed Jupyter using Anaconda but can't run it using terminal. Says command not found

Tags: python, macos, anaconda, jupyter

I just bought my very first Mac after using Windows my entire life and have been trying to install things. I am also still kind of a beginner at programming.

I installed Anaconda for Python 2.7 version, and then I installed the 3.7 version right after.

I tried going to terminal and typing jupyter notebook but it says:

```
zsh: command not found: jupyter
```

I am able to launch a jupyter notebook (I think) when I search for jupyter notebook in spotlight and executing the top hit.

I've been reading a lot on forums about this issue and see a lot of people talking about PATH which I am not really sure about.

I've seen people also post their `which python` information and theirs seem very different from mine:

```
which python3
usr/bin/python3
which python
usr/bin/python
```

Any help would be appreciated! Still learning how to set up this Mac. Thank you.

Comment: _I installed Anaconda for Python 2.7 version, and then I installed the 3.7 version right after._ Uuh, that sounds problematic. All you need to install is the most recent version of Anaconda 3.

Answer (score 0):

You might want to refer to this link https://jupyter-notebook-beginner-guide.readthedocs.io/en/latest/execute.html

> 3.1.2. Change Jupyter Notebook startup folder (Mac OS)
>
> To launch Jupyter Notebook App:
>
> Click on spotlight, type terminal to open a terminal window.
>   Enter the startup folder by typing `cd /some_folder_name`.
>   Type `jupyter notebook` to launch the Jupyter Notebook App The notebook interface will appear in a new browser window or tab.

From what I can understand you are not changing to the startup directory of Jupyter.

Answer (score 0):

You need to add jupyter to your path.

In your terminal, type in the following command:

```
export PATH="/PUT JUPYTER PATH HERE:$PATH"
```

Then try `jupyter notebook`

Reasoning: [*If installing using pip install --user, you must add the user-level bin directory to your PATH environment variable in order to launch jupyter lab*](https://jupyter.org/install)

Comment: When you say Jupyter path, does that just mean the location of where it is saved/installed on the Mac? Sorry if that's a dumb question :p

Comment: No worries. It should be where jupyter is on the system. For example `/usr/local/bin`, or `/usr/bin/python3/bin`. It will vary based on how you installed it. I am not that familiar with MacOS, so I can't tell you an exact location.